# Sublime Text 3 - Find and remove multiple </section> searching by "id" in multiple files

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have several html files with same `<section>` but different content.

I would like to know if it is possible for me to remove these sections in multiple files using the sublime text

Exemple:

```
<section class="all-classes" id="section1">
     content 
</section>
<section class="all-classes" id="section2-do-not-remove-section">
     content 
</section>
<section class="all-classes" id="section3">
     content 
</section>
<section class="all-classes" id="section4">
     content 
</section>
```

in this example I would like to remove sections 1, 3 and 4 and keep section 2

Comment: You want to delete all sections where the format of the id is `section#` where `#` is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,... ?

Comment: @Ouroborus From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help], software questions are allowed if they cover *"[...] software tools commonly used by programmers".* Sublime Text, like Vim, Emacs, VSCode, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+visual-studio-code) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic. Also, this is a programming question because the answer is to use an HTML parser.

Comment: This is actually a job for an HTML parser, not regex. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for a good laugh, but also for some good answers explaining why regex is not the tool for this job. [`BeautifulSoup4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [`lxml`](https://lxml.de) are the tools of choice for Python, I don't know about other languages.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by MattDMo in the comments, an HTML parser would be your best option for this job.

For simple cases where you just need a quick find+replace, you may use this RegEx:

```
<section.*id="section[\d]*"[\s\S]*?<\/section>
```

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/9AM6KA/1).

Where:

- `<section.*` - Catch text that starts with the tag `section` e.g. `<section class="all-classes"`
- `id="section[\d]*"` - Catch the ids where the name is `section` followed by a number e.g. `id="section32"`
- `[\s\S]*?` - Catch all characters (whitespaces or not) in a non-greedy way. This is to prevent spanning across multiple sections.
- `<\/section>` - Catch the closing tag `</section>`. Since this was captured in a non-greedy way, this will always be the closest `</section>` tag.

**WARNING:** If you have nested sections (a section within a section), this will not work. You have to use an HTML parser for that.